# Is making a python wrapper for the Azure-PowerShell SDK a stupid idea?

Tags: python, powershell, azure

My opinion of the Azure-Python SDK is not high for Azure RM. What takes 1 line in PowerShell takes 10 in Python. That is the opposite of what python is supposed to do.

So, my idea is to create python package which comes with a directory containing a few template .ps1 scripts. You would define a few variables like vmname, resourcegroup, location, etc... inject these into the .ps1 templates, then call commands from the REPL.

Right now I'm having trouble using the subprocess module to keep PS open until I tell it to close. As it stands now, I need to include

```
login-azurerm
```

and authenticate before running **any** command. This won't do. I'd like to fix this, but frankly right now I'm wondering whether or not the premise is a good idea to start with.

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: since you said powershell is easier and comprehensive would it not be easy to use that directly instead of python?

Comment: yesss you are right and I've thought about that. It's just a convenience thing. I want to be able to run azure-RM commands from the REPL while doing other non-Azure REPL stuff.

Basically, I'm lazy and don't wan to press alt+tab and change my language in the middle of scripting.

Comment: you can always go ahead and create a wrapper for the frequently used ps scripts you use :))

Comment: can you think of a way to keep PS open under python so I could run commands dynamically?

Comment: I'm hoping the issue is a symptom of my nascent subprocess-module knowlege. I understand the basics of how subprocess.Popen and subprocess.PIPE work together with the std<out,in,err> args. That's about it.

Comment: I am not too sure of how python to ps calls work.

Comment: It's probably a great idea. Any time anything is awkward, fixing it is a good idea. Alternatively, can you launch Python from powershell after having logged in? (Also, as it stands this question is really terrible for the SO format, encouraging discussion vs. actually answerable. I think you have enough rep to [join us in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) where we're happy to discuss things. I'd probably change this question so it's got a [mcve] and asks how to do the thing with subprocess and PS you want to do)

Answer (score 1):

@RobTruxal, the new CLI for Azure will be in Python and will be released as a preview soon. You can already try it from the github account:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli

The Azure SDK for Python is not supposed to mimic the Powershell cmdlets, but to be a language SDK (like C#, Java, Ruby, etc.).

If you have any suggestion/comments about the Python SDK itself, please do not hesitate to fill an issue on the issue tracker: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

(FYI, I'm the owner of the Python SDK repo at MS)

Answer (score 0):

@RobTruxal, It seems that a feasible way to call PowerShell in Python is using the module `subprocess`, such as the code below as reference.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "your-script.ps1", "arguments"])
```

You need to write your powershell script which includes `login-azurerm` command, and interaction with cmd that running python script.

Or you can choose the AzureCLI for cross platform in node.js as the command line tool for managing Azure Resoure.

Hope it helps.